# CFileDialog is visually different to Visual Studio File Dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mfc, cfiledialog

In **Visual Studio 2015** the **File Dialog** used by the IDE looks like this:

[image: File Dialog]

In my `MFC` application, when I use a `CFileDialog`, example:

```
CFileDialog dlgImport(TRUE,
    _T(".XSL"), _T(""), OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, strFilter, this);
```

My version is not the same:

[image: MFC File Dialog]

I like how the Visual Studio version shows the file type as wider control. Much neater.

How can I implement this behaviour?

Comment: I think, but I'm not positive, that Visual Studio uses a custom file open dialog. I *know* Office does.

Comment: @MarkRansom Why don't they make it available for users of their application? Would have been great.

Comment: Visual Studio is actually using an *older* version of the dialog. The new dialog has the file-type combobox off to the right. Open Notepad or any other app bundled with the system and you'll see this is what it looks like. This is the new [Common Item Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913.aspx), introduced with Vista. Visual Studio is using the old-school dialog, shown by calling [`GetOpenFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927.aspx). Of course, it uses `OFN_EXPLORER`, and may have custom logic extending it, too.

Comment: @CodyGray That explains it. Perhaps you should add that as the answer?

Comment: @MarkRansom How do you know?

Comment: Did you dive into the file dialog source? IIRC there was a boolean for setting the look, something like `m_bVistaStyle`. If it is private protected you will need to derive a class.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7.aspx

Comment: As per the link, that bool variable is set via the constructor. Last parameter.